# Calling a javascript function with a string?

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
var greet = function (name) {
    console.log("Hi " + name);
}
```

If I have a string "greet('eric')" is it possible to convert it to a function call passing "eric" as argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval() is your friend !
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Oh totally forgot eval(). Isn't it the other way around, its evil?

Comment: @weng Eval is only evil if you misuse it

Comment: The call of a thousand screaming virgins tearing at their flesh accompany your answer.

Comment: W3Schools bashing seems to be fashionable nowadays. They may be wrong in many aspects, but in their days (w3schools started in 1999) they were a great source of information to many. Maybe they'll catch up someday.

Answer (score 2):

You, me, him her and them fWord('ing') hate eval. There's always another way.

```
callMethod = function(def) {
    //all the variables are function references
    var approvedMethods = {greet: greet, love: love, marry: marry, murder: murder, suicide: suicide},
        split = def.split(/\(/); //split[0] contains function name, split[1] contains (unsplit) parameters

    //replace last ) and all possible string detonators left-over
    split[1] = split[1].replace(/\)$/, '').replace(/[\'\"]/g, '').split(','); //contains list of params

    if (!approvedMethods[split[0]])
        return 'No such function.';

    approvedMethods[split[0]].apply(window, split[1]);
}
//Called like this:
callMethod("greet('eric')");
```

Replace window reference with whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly, but are you looking for the [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function?

```
eval("greet('eric')");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is as easy as typing

```
eval("greet('eric')");
```

Answer (score 1):

without `eval`

```
var greet = function (name) {
      console.log("Hi " + name);
    },
    greetstr = 'greet("Eric")';

var greeter = greetstr.split('("');
window[greeter[0]]( greeter[1].replace(/\)|"/g,'') );
```

Bottom line 1: [use eval with care](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
Bottom line 2: avoid constructions like this.

Just to be sure you have all possibilities @ your disposal: `setTimeout(greetstr,0);`
<sub>Mmmm, there is an `eval` in there somewhere ;)</sub>

Comment: I guess eval() indeed is my friend in this case=)